# How can I get destination ip from tcp socket resulting from accept?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I do not mean what getsockname returns that is the address of the local interface, I mean the destination ip in the underlying ip packets (there are cases where those two are not equal, for instance in a transparent proxy scenario).

I do not want to use raw sockets to do that...

So I was wondering if there was some clever trick to find out the destination ip that appears in the packets...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`getsockname()` returns the target IP address of the SYN. Because of the [weak end system model](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.3.4.2) (also discussed [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.09.cableguy.aspx)), that may or may not be the address of the NIC via which the SYN was received.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my question, the option SO_ORIGINAL_DST:

```
 getsockopt(socket, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, &destAddr, &destAddrLen);
```

Hope this helps someone over there!

Comment: No. This retrieves the original destination *in the presence of a NAT device.* Not the same thing as you asked for.

Comment: @user207421 it does retrieve the original ip in the presence of NAT. [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/listener_filters/original_dst_filter) indeed use this to get the original ip

Answer (score 0):

@user2369060's answer is right. In practice, [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/listener_filters/original_dst_filter) indeed use `SO_ORIGINAL_DST` to get the original ip to achieve its functionality.